# Disable Help On Terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code

Visual Studio Code 1.68

Hi everyone
How to disable Help Tags?
For example in print function:

[see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APyqN.png)

Thank you very much already

Answer (score 0):

if I'm not wrong, in your picture you are using the editor, not the terminal.
To disable this, go to settings (F1 > "Open Settings (JSON))  and disable this option:

```
"editor.quickSuggestions": true,
```

Or if you want to disable it for a specific language:

```
  "[markdown]": {
    "editor.quickSuggestions": false
  }
```